# Rename multiple files in a folder, add a prefix (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames, prefix, batch-rename

I'd like to batch rename files in a folder, prefixing the folder's name into the new names. i.e. files in `C:\house chores\` will all be renamed `house chores - $old_name`.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

**Option 1: Using Windows PowerShell**

Open the windows menu. 
Type: "PowerShell" and open the 'Windows PowerShell' command window.

Goto folder with desired files: e.g. cd "C:\house chores"
Notice: address must incorporate quotes "" if there are spaces involved.

You can use 'dir' to see all the files in the folder. Using '|' will pipeline the output of 'dir' for the command that follows.

Notes: 'dir' is an alias of 'Get-ChildItem'. See: [wiki: cmdlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Comparison_of_cmdlets_with_similar_commands).
One can provide further functionality. e.g. 'dir -recurse' outputs all the files, folders and sub-folders.

What if I only want a range of files?

Instead of 'dir |' I can use:

```
dir | where-object -filterscript {($_.Name -ge 'DSC_20') -and ($_.Name -le 'DSC_31')} |
```

For batch-renaming with the directory name as a prefix:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

**Option 2: Using Command Prompt**

In the folder press shift+right-click : select 'open command-window here'

```
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "prefix - %a"
```

If there are a lot of files, it might be good to add an '@echo off' command before this and an 'echo on' command at the end.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The `@` in `@echo on` is not required. You just turned `@echo off`.

Comment: @IInspectableq, indeed. Corrected. Thanks for looking.

Comment: In Powershell `Get-ChildItem` doesn't provide any additional functionality over `dir`. `dir` is simply an alias so you can do `dir -recurse` if you want (`ls` is another alias for `Get-ChildItem` so you can use that as well if you wish). Also it would be worth mentioning the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` options on `Rename-Item` in case the OP doesn't know about them. (Might also be worth noting that `Rename-Item` can be shortened to `ren` or `rni` and the `-NewName` can be omitted as the new name is the default argument.)

Comment: Option 2 (after adding a missing `do`) does not work — after some files have been renamed, `for` finds them under the new name, adding the prefix again and again until the filename length limit is reached.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, I haven't encountered this, but I'll take you on your word. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: when using option 2 i get `ren was unexpected at this time.` any idea why?

Comment: @billgates The word `do` is missing in his answer. it should be `for %a in (.) do ren "%a" "prefix - %a"`

Comment: @SergeyVlasov That happens in both Options.  The only way to avoid that would be to have the rename place it above the original.  Or perhaps move it to a different folder after renaming.

Comment: How to exclude sub folder names?

Comment: How can this command - dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name} be an answer. It made a mess of names. Iyt kept on prefixing -     ERROR: At line:1 char:7
+ dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.PathTooLongException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: For anybody having trouble with option 2 (the for loop continually re-finds the renamed files), see this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1028054/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-windows?newreg=c63385d608a34030b48f8a863d23d6e5

Answer (score 67):

The problem with the two Powershell answers here is that the prefix can end up being duplicated since the script will potentially run over the file both before and after it has been renamed, depending on the directory being resorted as the renaming process runs.  To get around this, simply use the `-Exclude` option:

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude {$_.Directory.Name + " - "} | rename-item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name }
```

This will prevent the process from renaming any one file more than once.

Comment: Please consider adding to your suggestion a less specific example, which includes $_.Directory.Name

Comment: This one works, you specify the name after -NewName { and use that same name in the exclude part. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

Free Software '[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)' also works well (and is powerful for advanced tasks also). [Download](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) and installation takes a minute.

See [screenshots](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php) and [tutorial](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Tutorial.php) on original website.

--

I cannot provide step-by-step screenshots as the images will have to be released under [Creative Commons License](https://creativecommons.org/), and I do not own the screenshots of the software.

*Disclaimer:* I am not associated with the said software/company in any way. I liked the product for my own task, it serves OP's and similar requirements, thus recommending.

Comment: Started using it myself at some point. +1 for adding something to the thread.

Comment: This answer is out of topic! -1

Comment: @MarcoDemaio Thanks for feedback. The OP wants to get a task done, and the linked software makes it easy to do. I believe, complexity of the solution does not make it more relevant.

Comment: @GopalAggarwal: sorry, you are right I read in his question "I'd like to batch rename files in a folder" and I thought he was looking for a Windows batch file. I removed my -1.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio That's okay. :)

Comment: Very useful. Powers with GUI.

Comment: I started using this utility after finding this answer and it's fantastic. The other answers are great if you want to get more experience with Powershell or Batch, but if you just want to get the job done this utility is the way to go

Comment: I came here looking for alternatives to BRU. The interface is horrible, and it crashes a lot.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me, first cd in the directory that you would like to change the filenames to and then run the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName { "house chores-" + $_.Name }
```

Online Docs

- [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6)
- [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6)

Comment: This causes an infinite loop until the file name reaches the Windows limit. Instead use @Dave.Gugg's response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37279979/2179408

Answer (score 8):

I was tearing my hair out because for some items, the renamed item would get renamed again (repeatedly, unless max file name length was reached).  This was happening both for Get-ChildItem and piping the output of dir.  I guess that the renamed files got picked up because of a change in the alphabetical ordering.  I solved this problem in the following way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -OutVariable dirs
foreach ($i in $dirs) { Rename-Item $i.name ("<MY_PREFIX>"+$i.name) }
```

This "locks" the results returned by Get-ChildItem in the variable $dirs and you can iterate over it without fear that ordering will change or other funny business will happen.

Dave.Gugg's tip for using -Exclude should also solve this problem, but this is a different approach; perhaps if the files being renamed already contain the pattern used in the prefix.

(Disclaimer: I'm very much a PowerShell n00b.)

Answer (score 6):

Based on @ofer.sheffer answer, this is the CMD variant for adding an affix (this is not the question, but this page is still the #1 google result if you search affix). It is a bit different because of the extension.

```
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%~a" "%~na-affix%~xa"
```

You can change the "-affix" part.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ofer.sheffer answer this command will mass rename and **append the current date** to the filename. ie "file.txt" becomes "20180329 - file.txt" for all files in the current folder

```
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2% - %a"
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using **PowerShell** with this same requirement (adding a prefix to a file name in a directory), you will likely find that if you use some form of...

```
Get-ChildItem ./ | Rename-Item -NewName {"prefix" + $_.Name}
```

...that the files will continually get the prefix added in a loop until the windows file name length limit is reached. So instead of "prefixFile1.txt" you get: "prefixprefixprefixprefixprefixprefix...File1.txt". The cause of this is `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet will continually pipe the newly named file back into the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

Solution for this isn't too bad, just make use of PowerShell's [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--).

```
$(Get-ChildItem ./) | Rename-Item -NewName {"prefix" + $_.Name}
```

Putting `$()` around a `Get-ChildItem` ensures that all of the currently existing files get returned first and are then piped into `Rename-Item`, rather than piped in dynamically without the subexpression operator. Just keep in mind if you have millions+ files/items as it may take awhile to iterate all of them before any renames are carried out.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I learned alot from the various answers but came up with my own solution as a function. This should dynamically add the parent folder as a prefix to all files that matches a certain pattern but only if it does not have that prefix already.

```
function Add-DirectoryPrefix($pattern) {
    # To debug, replace the Rename-Item with Select-Object
    Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Filter $pattern -Recurse | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike ($_.Directory.Name + '*')} | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '-' + $_.Name}
        # Select-Object -Property Directory,Name,@{Name = 'NewName'; Expression= {$_.Directory.Name + '-' + $_.Name}}
}
```

https://gist.github.com/kmpm/4f94e46e569ae0a4e688581231fa9e00