# Add a numeric suffix to filenames in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filenames

I want to rename a large number of files to somthing like `S001`, `S002`, etc..
I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874915/rename-multiple-files-in-a-folder-add-a-prefix-windows) to add a prefix:

```
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "prefix - %a"
```

So I tried to modify it so a variable would increment with the `for`, something like this:

```
for /l %x in (1,1,5) do %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "SQ00%x"
```

Obviously that's wrong, I later read that `/l` makes for work in numeric values instead of filenames, so `%a` doesn't mean anything (correct me if I'm wrong).

So I would like to know how to increment a value in `for` loop using the file names of files inside a folder.

**EDIT**

I now managed to write a batch that will rename files, and:

- do it in a specific directory
- with a specific file extension
- tells you how many files of that extension are in that directory
- asks for a new name, to which it will later add the numeric suffixes
- loops to change files in different directories

  ```
  ECHO OFF

  Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  :start

  cls

  echo "%cd%"

  echo where are the files?        
  set/p "files=>"        
  cd "%files%"

  echo now in:    
  echo "%cd%"

  echo files extension:
  set/p "ext=>"

  ::amount of files in the directory
  set/a cnt=0    
  for %%a in (*.%ext%) do set /a cnt+=1
  echo File count = %cnt%
  PAUSE

  echo new file name:
  set/p "name=>"

  set/a Count=1
  for /r %%a in (*.%ext%) do (
  echo !Count!
  ren "%%a" "%name%!Count!.%ext%"
  set /a Count=Count+1
  )

  PAUSE

  goto start
  ```

The problem now is that the FOR loop that renames the files does 1 more loop that the amount of files in the directory and I don't know why

[image: run]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
    set /a Count=Count+1
    echo ren "%%a" "!Count! - %%a"
    )
```

Is one way. See `set /?` and `setlocal /?`.

From Windows NT Command Shell

> Parentheses can also be used to enter multi-line commands. If a command line ends with one or more sets of unbalanced parentheses, the command line is assumed to continue on the next line. If the command was entered interactively, the shell prompts for more input until all parentheses balance. If the command is part of a script, the shell reads additional script lines until all the parentheses balance. For example:
>
> ```
> 1. C:\>(
> 2. More?echo command1
> 3. More?echo command2
> 4. More?)
> 5. command1
> 6. command2
> ```
>
> The first line consists only of an open parenthesis. The shell detects this, and prompts for more input. Next, two ECHO commands are entered. Finally, a closing parenthesis balances the opening parenthesis and the command is complete. The shell then executes the compound command, which executes the two individual ECHO commands.
> Individual commands do not span lines in multi-line commands. The end of a physical line always terminates a simple command (either as typed or as entered in a script file). Notice in the preceding example how the end of the physical line terminated each ECHO command.